# MySQL query that returns all the rows that have been added in the last 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

I have a table that contains the next columns:

```
ip(varchar 255), index(bigint 20), time(timestamp)
```

each time something is inserted there, the time column gets current timestamp.
I want to run a query that returns all the rows that have been added in the last 24 hours.
This is what I try to execute:

```
SELECT ip, index FROM users WHERE ip = 'some ip' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOURS,time,NOW()) < 24
```

And it doesn't work.

Comment: According to the mysql manual, the unit should be HOUR not HOURS. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd

Comment: @MDMA - I think you have the answer, definitely HOUR (singular)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HOURS should be HOUR. See the documentantion for [TIMESTAMPADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) to see the valid values of the `unit` parameter:

> TIMESTAMPADD(unit,interval,datetime_expr)
>
> Adds the integer expression interval to the date or datetime expression datetime_expr. The unit for interval is given by the unit argument, which should be one of the following values: FRAC_SECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.

So your query should be:

```
SELECT ip, index
FROM   users
WHERE  ip = 'some ip'
AND    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time, NOW()) < 24
```

Note also that this query won't be able to take advantage of an index on time, if one exists. It could be more efficient to rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT ip, index
FROM   users
WHERE  ip = 'some ip'
AND    time > NOW() - interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [date time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) of mysql

```
SELECT something FROM tbl_name
    WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= time;
```

Comment: my guess would be that this will actually use an index on `time` whereas comparing timestampdiff(xxx,curdate(),time) to a constant wouldn't, am I correct?

Comment: @araqnid: Yes, if an index exists, this query can use it. This applies to this answer, my second suggestion, Salman A's answer and Paul G's.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider doing it the other way round. Rather than subtract 24 hours from each time, calculate the time 24 hours ago (once), and then check your time values against that. Very likely more optimal, though I'm not too familiar with mySql

```
SELECT ip, index FROM users WHERE ip = 'some ip' AND time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), HOUR, 24)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ip, index
FROM users
WHERE ip = 'some ip'
AND time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

This assumes that you do not have "future" times in your table. If there are, append this to your where clause:

```
AND time <= NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

> TIMESTAMPADD(unit,interval,datetime_expr)
>
> Adds the integer expression interval
>   to the date or datetime expression
>   datetime_expr. The unit for interval
>   is given by the unit argument, which
>   should be one of the following values:
>   FRAC_SECOND (microseconds), SECOND,
>   MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH,
>   QUARTER, or YEAR.
>
> Beginning with MySQL 5.1.24, it is
>   possible to use MICROSECOND in place
>   of FRAC_SECOND with this function, and
>   FRAC_SECOND is deprecated. FRAC_SECOND
>   is removed in MySQL 5.5.
>
> The unit value may be specified using
>   one of keywords as shown, or with a
>   prefix of SQL_TSI_. For example, DAY
>   and SQL_TSI_DAY both are legal.
>
> mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,1,'2003-01-02');
>
> -> '2003-01-02 00:01:00'
>
> mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK,1,'2003-01-02');
>
> -> '2003-01-09'

So ...

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

should be what you want